# hide a div when input or div is not focused using pure css

Tags: html, css

I want to show a div only when:

- input is focused.
- div is focused.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <div>
        ...some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
input + div {
    background: #f0a;
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

input:focus + div { 
    display: block; 
}
```

**Current Behavior:**

- When Focus is on `input`, I can see the `div`.
- When focus from `input` is gone, I can not see `div`.
- When I try to click on `div`, it hides.

I dont want that behavior (When I try to click on `div`, it hides).

I want a pure css solution if possible.

As I am using reactJS, I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: `When I try to click on div, it hides.` it's logic since you loose the focus of input

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes its expected by taking a look at my code. But I want to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> div is focused

`div` elements by default are not focusable. If you want to force them to be focusable add `tabindex="0"` (see [MDN: tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex))

If you want the element to be focusable but not via keyboard navigation - then add `tabindex="-1"`

Now that the `div` is focusable, we can use [the `:focus-within` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within)) to check any element within the container div that is focused:

```
.wpr:focus-within div {
  display: block;
}
```

Now we can also remove the CSS which check whether the input is focused.

```css
input + div {
    background: #f0a;
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


.wpr:focus-within div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
    <input type="text" />
    <div tabindex="-1">
        ...some content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** If browser compatibility is an issue (lack of IE/Edge support for `:focus-within`) you could use @Temani Afif's solution as a fallback

```css
input+div {
  background: #f0a;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.wpr:focus-within div {
  display: block;
}

input:focus + div {
  display: block;
}

.wpr div:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <input type="text" />
  <div tabindex="-1">
    ...some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it looks good enough. But when I press TAB key on textbox, I don't want to focus div, I want to hide it. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Yes, use `tabindex="-1"` instead of `tabindex="0"`

Comment: That did the trick. Your answer looks more appropriate, so I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but there is a bit twist in my case. I have a table inside div. When I click on any item inside table, I use a `selected` class to be attached to the clicked item. I am successful in doing that. But now my requirement is that: when I click on any tr inside table, I want to hide the div.  Can you please help me?

Comment: To make my intentions clear: I am creating a component in react which is very much similar to ComboBox in desktop applications, but has much more features than that like templates and lazy loading.

Comment: I have never used codepen with react, so I can't get it to work. But I have pasted my jsx code in js section of codepen. Here is the link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooKVGb

Comment: think you'll need to add javascript for that requirement. When you click a `tr` element you could remove focus from the `div` - something like `anotherElement.focus();`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. I have done that. Also got react to work on codepen. I have added a button outside of wrapper and now it works like a charm. Thanks again. Here is the link in case if you want to refer it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooKVGb

Answer (score 2):

You can add `hover` style on the div to make it show so that when you click on it (when you hover on it) it won't hide even if you loose the focus :

```css
input+div.select {
  background: #f0a;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

input:focus+div.select {
  display: block;
}

div.select:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="select">
    ...some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks good. Events like click on div are also firing. Thanks, its the exact answer that I was looking for.

Comment: The issue here is that if you hover out of the div after it is clicked - the div disappears.... but maybe the OP is ok with this.

Comment: @Danield yes i think this is intended, as he want the div to remain on focus and on hovering ... so if both condition are not the div disappears